# What is the creature Yuyukkhura?

Tags: animals, reference-request

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_legendary_creatures_in_Hindu_mythology) and [this dictionary](https://dsal.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/app/apte_query.py?qs=yuyukkhurah&matchtype=default), there exists a type of beast that is some sort of small-sized mix of a wolf and a tiger (may be related to the hyena). It is called a *Yuyukkhara*. There seems to be a similar creature in Ethiopian folklore.

Is there any scriptural basis for this creature? I cannot find it anywhere in any sacred te, and it seems to be very obscure given that there are barely any relevant hits on Google for it.

(I would have dismissed this as random fake information on Wikipedia, but the dictionary is from an academic institution and the publication itself is fairly reliable.)

Answer (score 0):

The yuyukkhura:
Quoting-
Yuyukkhura (युयुक्खुर).—A species of a small tiger or wolf; a hyena (kṣudravyāghra).
Derivable forms: yuyukkhuraḥ (युयुक्खुरः).

Following up if kshdravyaghra occurs: it is found in the Padma Puran, side by side with tarakshu:-
पंथानं समतीत्य दुस्तरमिमं दूरादवीयस्तरंक्षुद्र व्याघ्रतरक्षुकंटकफणिप्रत्यार्थिभिः ।
संकुलम् ।
आगत्य प्रथमव्ययं कृपणवाग्याचेज्जनः ।
कर्परीश्रीमद्वारिगदाधर प्रतिदिनं त्वां द्रष्टुमुत्कंठते ॥ ४५ ॥
Translations of the Padma Puran are plenty, but could not locate due to mismatch of location( book,chapter, verse).
Obviously some horror or difficulty is being described.. to me it seems that if you start going away from the established path you will encounter ghouls...is the purport.